# Julia - exponentiating a matrix returned from another function

Tags: julia

I have functions `f1` and `f2` returning matrices `m1` and `m2`, which are calculated using `Diagonal, Tridiagonal, SymTridiagonal` from LinearAlgebra package.

In a new function `f3` I try computing

```
j = m1 - m2*im
m3 = exp(j)
```

but this gives a `Method error` on computation unless I use `j=Matrix(m1-m2*im)`, saying that `no matching method for exp(::LinearAlgebra.Tridiagonal ...)`

My question is how can I do this computation in the most optimal way? I am a total beginner in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a very special structure of `j` (i.e. if its exponential is sparse - which is unlikely) the best you can do AFAICT is to use a dense matrix as an input to `exp`:

```
m3 = LinearAlgebra.exp!([float(x) for x in Tridiagonal(dl, d, du)])
```

If you expect `m3` to be sparse then I think currently there is no special algorithm implemented for that case in Julia.

Note that I use `exp!` to do operation in place and use a comprehension to make sure the argument to `exp!` is dense. As `exp!` expects `LinearAlgebra.BlasFloat` (that is `Union{Complex{Float32}, Complex{Float64}, Float32, Float64}`) I use `float` to make sure that elements of `j` are appropriately converted. Note that it might fail if you work with e.g. `BigFloat` or `Float16` values - in this case you have to do an appropriate conversion to the expected types yourself.

Comment: `j` is a tridiagonal matrix with identically zero diagonal. So I do expect it to be very sparse. It's actually `J_- = Jx - i Jy` from quantum mechanics. If you have a good suggestion for that it would be very helpful. Meanwhile I will try this.

Comment: In this case probably writing a custom exponentiation function taking advantage of this information is probably best.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I ended up doing. It turned out to be lot more simple. I had however tried using PyCall to import expm from scipy to do this part but Julia still didn't do it as fast as python. I hope the sparse algorithm gets implemented soon.